# How to make a normal lines numbering in EditText?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-edittext, edittextpreference

I am making a text editor for Android and I would like to show the number of every line in the`EditText`.

My solution was to make a `TextView` with lines numbers and place an `EditText` next to `TextView`. Like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lines_numbering_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="1\n"/>
        <EditText
            <!--EditText options here-->
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This works fine but there is one fact... If the lines count is about 600, when `TextView's` `onMeasure` method is called, it makes the app to freeze for a 0.5 seconds.

So, what can I do to improve the performance of TextView or are there any good solutions of numbering lines?

Comment: I think this is a reasonable approach, but instead of adding Views to a `LinearLayout`, you should use a `RecyclerView` with a row type that consists of a `TextView` (number) and `EditText` (content), and update the rows in response to a carriage return (either with a key listener listening for a 'new line' press, or a `TextWatcher` monitoring for the `System.lineSeparator()` symbol)

Comment: @PPartisan Yes, it could be a really good solution, but in this case we can't move the cursor between lines

Answer (score 0):

The line number view can be seen and implemented as a ruler. All it needs as input is the line height. From there it can display increasing line numbers at the proper vertical positions. It need not know the number of lines in the content view.